# Storing jQuery function result to MySQL database

Tags: jquery, mysql

I wasn't intending to start into backend yet but after I managed the registration/login of users through PHP, I decided that I wanted to store users' coin flip results. What do I need to learn to be able to do this? Ajax?

Here is my jQuery coinflip function, but I'm really looking for more of a direction as to what would be the best way of doing this and what I'd need to learn to do so (spent a long time googling but not found a clear path):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#coin").on("click", function() {
    $("h1").toggle();    
    var coinResult = Math.random();    
    $("#coin").removeClass();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (coinResult <= 0.5) {
        $("#coin").addClass("heads");
        console.log(heads);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("h2").text("You got HEADS")
        }, 3000);
      } else {
        $("#coin").addClass("tails");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("h2").text("You got TAILS")
        }, 3000);
        console.log(tails);
      }
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: Something like this?   $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"server.php?p=add",
       data:{coinResult:coinResult},
       success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
       }
    });

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to be working but I expect it's just a case of user error on my end!